# Service facade calls - security checking

Tags: .net, security

For a service facade implemented in .NET, is there an option (e.g. a 3rd party library) that can be used to perform some security checking? I mean some kind of access control list based checking for every method, based on their roles.

Answer (score 0):

How is the façade presented? A separate assembly? Web service? Some weird funky custom thing? Also how is authentication happening? AD? Something else?

If the service layer is running in the context of the calling user (i.e. the thread has a filled IPrinciple/IUser context appropriate to the user) you could use CAS by placing

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand,Role="*role*")]
```

on your methods. This would throw a security exception if the authenticated user was in the role/group you specified.

Comment: Separate assembly; form authentication.

Comment: But still contained within the web site itself, or a separate application with exposed web services?